# Calculate Spark column value depending on another row value on the same column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on Apache spark 2.3.0 cloudera4 and I have an issue processing a Dataframe.

I've got this input dataframe:

```
+---+---+----+
| id| d1| d2 |
+---+---+----+
|  1|   | 2.0|
|  2|   |-4.0|
|  3|   | 6.0|
|  4|3.0|    |
+---+---+----+
```

And I need this output:

```
+---+---+----+----+
| id| d1| d2 |  r |
+---+---+----+----+
|  1|   | 2.0| 7.0|
|  2|   |-4.0| 5.0|
|  3|   | 6.0| 9.0|
|  4|3.0|    | 3.0|
+---+---+.---+----+
```

Which is, from an iterating perspective, get the biggest id row (4) and put the d1 value on the r column, then take the next row (3) and put r[4] + d2[3] on r column, and so on.

Is it posible to do something like that on Spark? because I will need a computed value from a row to calculate the value for another row.

Comment: The question is wrong or incomplete d2 column value for id=2 changes in input and output, but you have nowhere explained that s2 re-compute is required.

Comment: how do you sort the column d2? Or can it be different?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? The important bit is `sum($"r1").over(Window.orderBy($"id".desc)` which calculates a cumulative sum of a column. Other than that, I'm creating a couple of helper columns to get the max id and get the ordering right.

```
val result = df
  .withColumn("max_id", max($"id").over(Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)))
  .withColumn("r1", when($"id" === $"max_id", $"d1").otherwise($"d2"))
  .withColumn("r", sum($"r1").over(Window.orderBy($"id".desc)))
  .drop($"max_id").drop($"r1")
  .orderBy($"id")
result.show


+---+----+----+---+
| id|  d1|  d2|  r|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|null| 2.0|7.0|
|  2|null|-4.0|5.0|
|  3|null| 6.0|9.0|
|  4| 3.0|null|3.0|
+---+----+----+---+
```